# Most accurate way to spot series of True values in a list/array, ignoring sole True values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Based on a criteria applied on variables in a dataframe, I have series of `True`/`False` values in a list.The index of range of interest is the portion of the list
where there is a series of true values **(around 15-25 `True` values in a row)**. And there are random `True` values in the list as well. Please see the **jutted out portion** of list below. I need to extract the start and end index of `True` portion. **Ignoring the sole `True` rows.**  The data pattern will always remain the same, So the program will be valid for my other data-sets; though it shouldn't matter anyway because this question is for the **data below**.

```
actual_data = [
        True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, True, False, False,  

   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,  

        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False,
        False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, True
    ]
```

So the part of list of interest is in above list is `actual_data[83:105]` . I need a method to spot start and end point of this region.

Comment: Can the downvote be explained, so I can make appropriate edits. I don't have a code attempt. It's not something I could come up to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you got a downvote because there is no code attempt and because this is a rather basic question. However I've provided an answer that should be helpful to you.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I believe you should be more specific about your output. Do you want the longest sequence? All those of length between 15-25?

Comment: Also: use `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thanks, I've never faced this kind of programming problem. I couldn't define it well enough.

Comment: _"I need a method to spot start and end point of this region"_ First you need to come up with criteria for _identifying_ it, which is lacking here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell He gives the criteria (15-25 `True` values in a row) and an example that satisfies the condition (`actual_data[83:105]`). Of course there are gaps, such as what to do if there are multiple regions matching the given criteria, but there is enough guidance for a naive implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a counter and loop over the enumerated list. For every true encountered, add 1 to the counter. For every false, check if the counter is in a certain range (for example 15-25). If it is in the range, `counter - index` and `index` and will give you the start and end indexes. If it is not in the range, reset the counter to 0 and continue looping.

The following has been tested with your data and returns `(83, 105)`. Make any changes you'd like to suit it to your own needs. I suggest adding the desired minimum and maximum range as additional parameters for more flexibility.

```
def extract_range(my_list):
    counter = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
        if value == True:
            counter += 1
        else:
            if 15 <= counter <= 25:
                return (index - counter, index)
            else:
                counter = 0
    return (-1, -1)
```

Comment: It's giving me an error for `counter++` should be `counter += 1` right?

Comment: Yes, I made that change locally but forgot to update here. Good catch.